# How can I geotag many people inside building in website?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, geolocation

I would like **geotag** 200 people **inside a room** (with a correct precise).

All of them will have a website access by smartphone (iOS/Android). I would like make a diagram of this room and show on an other view : "The third is here / The fifth is here ...".

I have for this some Airport Extrem/Express.

I can use all **web developpement**, but I don't really know what I can use.

I just ask how can I geotag inside building with wifi connection.

I'm waiting for your answer.

Comment: Simple answer would be that you can not. In general all of the people would get exactly same location, and with the accuracy inside rooms in general the location fetched might not be pointing into the room.

Comment: If i use RFID, what do you think ?

Comment: Supposing that might work. if you would have something in the room in multple places which would identify where those ID things are located inside the room. Of course you could also use low-range transmitters (f.ex. Bluetooth, etc,)in known location with known range, then as you could identify the area covered by the transmitter, you could make fingerprints of the room areas, and get some-sort-of-accuracy inside the room

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both types of devices make use of GPS as well as the location of the wireless network they are connected to.

With all devices in one room, the accuracy of the technologies used is just not enough. Especially in buildings the accuracy is usually not good and you would have people showing up randomly inside the room (and also outside of the room).

Comment: Using GPS indoors generally does not work.. i.e. its using even more inaccurate methods for getting the location, just as I pointed in my comment.